# search for all occurrences and replace with a different one in python with regex

Tags: python

I'm new here.

I'm trying to find a specific pattern in text and replacing with different pattern in python.

What I'm trying to do is finding all the `". [A-Z]"` and replacing only `". "` with `".\n"`.

For example this text:

```
Oligocatal Magnesio 20 Fiale Glucosate 2MlSpecificheOligocatal Magnesio 20 Fiale Glucosate 2Ml. Le immagini dei prodotti sono puramente indicative e potrebbero pertanto non essere perfettamente rappresentative del packaging o comunque differire in alcune parti, delle caratteristiche del prodotto, differendo per colori, dimensioni o contenuto. Alcune decorazioni, confezioni regalo e oggetti inseriti e simili potrebbero considerarsi non corrispondenti nelle immagini ai fini della presentazione del prodotto non saranno spediti negli ordini. Le denominazioni dei prodotti, gli ingredienti e le percentuali indicati nelle descrizioni sono puramente indicativi, potrebbero subire variazioni o aggiornamenti da parte delle aziende produttrici. Non &egrave possibile adeguarsi in tempo reale a tali aggiornamenti, le foto e le informazioni tecniche dei prodotti inseriti su  () possono differire da quelle riportate in etichetta o in altro modo diffuse dalle aziende produttrici. L'unico elemento di identificazione risulta essere il codice ministeriale MINSAN. La farmacia  () non garantisce la veridicit&agrave e l'attualit&agrave delle informazioni pubblicate e declina ogni responsabilit&agrave in ordine ad eventuali errori, omissioni o mancati aggiornamenti delle stesse.  () non si assume responsabilit&agrave per danni di qualsiasi natura che possano derivare dall'accesso alle informazioni pubblicate.. FarmaciaUno: Bellezza & Salute!
```

Should be:

```
Oligocatal Magnesio 20 Fiale Glucosate 2MlSpecificheOligocatal Magnesio 20 Fiale Glucosate 2Ml.
Le immagini dei prodotti sono puramente indicative e potrebbero pertanto non essere perfettamente rappresentative del packaging o comunque differire in alcune parti, delle caratteristiche del prodotto, differendo per colori, dimensioni o contenuto. Alcune decorazioni, confezioni regalo e oggetti inseriti e simili potrebbero considerarsi non corrispondenti nelle immagini ai fini della presentazione del prodotto non saranno spediti negli ordini.
Le denominazioni dei prodotti, gli ingredienti e le percentuali indicati nelle descrizioni sono puramente indicativi, potrebbero subire variazioni o aggiornamenti da parte delle aziende produttrici.
Non &egrave possibile adeguarsi in tempo reale a tali aggiornamenti, le foto e le informazioni tecniche dei prodotti inseriti su  () possono differire da quelle riportate in etichetta o in altro modo diffuse dalle aziende produttrici.
L'unico elemento di identificazione risulta essere il codice ministeriale MINSAN. la farmacia  () non garantisce la veridicit&agrave e l'attualit&agrave delle informazioni pubblicate e declina ogni responsabilit&agrave in ordine ad eventuali errori, omissioni o mancati aggiornamenti delle stesse.  () non si assume responsabilit&agrave per danni di qualsiasi natura che possano derivare dall'accesso alle informazioni pubblicate..
FarmaciaUno: Bellezza & Salute
```

what i need is find all ". [A-Z]" and replace only ". " with ".\n"... what i want is find "point followed with 1 space and uppercase letter" and replace only "point and space" with "point and newline"

Comment: I doubt that you need regular expression here at all. Just use `text = text.replace(". ", "\n")`

Comment: thanks but in this case it will replace all ". "; what i need is find all ". [A-Z]" and replace only ". " with ".\n"... what i want is find "point followed with 1 space and uppercase letter" and replace only "point and space" with "point and newline"

Answer (score 0):

Could something like this work?

```
import re

s = "per colori, dimensioni o contenuto. Alcune decorazioni. Altre cose"
s = re.sub(r'. ([A-Z])', r'.\n\1', s)
print(s)
```

Output:

```
per colori, dimensioni o contenuto.
Alcune decorazioni.
Altre cose
```